# Cryptic error message when loading clsql

Tags: common-lisp, clisp, asdf, clsql

I'm trying to access a database from within CLISP using clsql. Since I'm running ubuntu, I installed all the necessary packages using apt-get, and to load them, I included the following bit of code at the top of my source file:

```
(asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op 'clsql-sqlite3)
```

However, when I run this, I get the following output:

```
; Loading system definition from /usr/share/common-lisp/systems/clsql-sqlite3.asd into #<PACKAGE ASDF0>
; Registering #<SYSTEM CLSQL-SQLITE3> as CLSQL-SQLITE3
; Loading system definition from /usr/share/common-lisp/systems/clsql-uffi.asd into #<PACKAGE ASDF0>
; Registering #<SYSTEM CLSQL-UFFI> as CLSQL-UFFI
; Loading system definition from /usr/share/common-lisp/systems/uffi.asd into #<PACKAGE ASDF0>
*** - component CLSQL-UFFI-SYSTEM::UFFI does not match version 2.0, required by #<SYSTEM "clsql-uffi">
```

I looked into uffi.asd, and the version is listed as 2.0.0. I tried to find some kind of tutorial on how to load and initialize the package with no luck. Any ideas on how I could get this working?

Comment: Also, I can't use sbcl because I have almost 5k lines of code using clisp sockets. Fun!

Comment: Have you tried using [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/) instead of invoking ASDF directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found that, contrary to its package description, cl-sql does NOT support clisp. So, I guess that Steel Bank is going to be the way to go. Sorry for the worthless question.